# Set a trigger's property to a child

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, styles

How can I set the trigger to be depend on a children's property?
Like I want to change the *header* of my *Expander* depending whether the *Expander*'s *ListView* 
does have children or not.

But I always get an Comilor error, that HasItems can not be resolved...

```
<Expander Header="Expand to add new ports">
  <Expander.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
      <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="Content.HasItems" Value="False">
           <Setter Property="Header" Value="No children" />
         </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Expander.Resources>
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SomeItems}">
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `DataTrigger` bound to the `ListView` using `ElementName`:

```
<Expander>
    <Expander.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="Expand to add new ports" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ListView, Path=HasItems}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="No children" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Expander.Resources>
    <ListView x:Name="ListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SomeItems}">
    </ListView>
</Expander>
```

Also note that if you set a property along with the declaration of the control the `Setter` in the trigger won't have any effect.

Use this:

```
<Setter Property="Header" Value="Expand to add new ports" />
```

Instead of this:

```
<Expander Header="Expand to add new ports">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your code -

First, you should `set the property in style setter` instead of declaring it locally.

Second, use `DataTrigger` in place of Trigger.

```
<Expander>
  <Expander.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
      <Setter Property="Header" Value="Expand to add new ports"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SomeItems.Count}" Value="0">
             <Setter Property="Header" Value="No children" />
         </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Expander.Style>
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SomeItems}">
  </ListView>
</Expander>
```